# How to trigger setState() of any other Stateful Class?

Tags: flutter

I have two stateful states, ABCState and XYZState, I want to call `setState()` on ABCState from XYZState so that I can trigger a redraw of ABCState

```
class ABCState extends State<ABC> {

}

& 

Class XYZState extends State<XYZ> {
    // Call .setState() of ABCState
}
```

I tried to play around with keys, but somehow not able to do so. Appreciate your help

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that? Use case?

Comment: @HemanthRaj  My usecase is to redraw all widgets because of some user actions.

Comment: I suppose on calling `setState`, flutter redraws only those widgets whose state is changed. Why would you redraw all the widgets. You are putting more load on rendering process.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778488/force-flutter-to-redraw-all-widgets) is similar.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad idea.
But if you want to do it, you can :

- Use `GlobalKey`, which allows to get state/context/widget
- Use `BuildContext` of the children of your desired stateful widget. Using `context.ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<MyStatefulWidget>());`