# How to change theme of flutter App in real time

Tags: flutter

I have an app in flutter with about 30 screens.
App needs to be in 2 themes, based on boolean downloaded from rest API. Basically most of colors are changed, its like applying theme to the app which will change coloring of most widgets. Not just primaryColor, but textcolors, backgrounds, ...

What is the best approach to do it? Is it possible to define 2 different themes and switch between them in real time, or I just have to do some helping classw hich will provide colors based on this boolean?

Comment: Maybe something like that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49164592/flutter-how-to-change-the-materialapp-theme-at-runtime