# Change the app theme at runtime

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm beginner to Flutter.
How I can change the whole application theme to dark theme from light theme?

Let's say I have below code for Light Theme :

```
final ThemeData dTheme = new ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
  primaryColor: Colors.orangeAccent[100],
  primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.light,
);
```

and the Dark Theme :

```
final ThemeData lTheme = new ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
  primaryColor: Colors.indigoAccent[100],
  primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
);
```

I want to change theme on click of button at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a specific case of the question answered here: [Force Flutter to redraw all widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778488/force-flutter-to-redraw-all-widgets)

Take a look at the Stocks sample mentioned in that question, taking note especially of: 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/stocks/lib/main.dart
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/stocks/lib/stock_settings.dart

Take note of the following:

1. Theme is specified from `_configuration`, which is updated by `configurationUpdater`
2. `configurationUpdater` is passed on to children of the app that need it
3. Children can call that configurationUpdater, which in turn sets state at the root of the app, which in turn redraws the app using the specified theme

Below code might help you:

```
// How to use: Any Widget in the app can access the ThemeChanger
// because it is an InheritedWidget. Then the Widget can call
// themeChanger.theme = [blah] to change the theme. The ThemeChanger
// then accesses AppThemeState by using the _themeGlobalKey, and
// the ThemeChanger switches out the old ThemeData for the new
// ThemeData in the AppThemeState (which causes a re-render).

final _themeGlobalKey = new GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'app_theme');

class AppTheme extends StatefulWidget {

  final child;

  AppTheme({
    this.child,
  }) : super(key: _themeGlobalKey);

  @override
  AppThemeState createState() => new AppThemeState();
}

class AppThemeState extends State<AppTheme> {

  ThemeData _theme = DEV_THEME;

  set theme(newTheme) {
    if (newTheme != _theme) {
      setState(() => _theme = newTheme);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ThemeChanger(
      appThemeKey: _themeGlobalKey,
      child: new Theme(
        data: _theme,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ThemeChanger extends InheritedWidget {

  static ThemeChanger of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(ThemeChanger);
  }

  final ThemeData theme;
  final GlobalKey _appThemeKey;

  ThemeChanger({
    appThemeKey,
    this.theme,
    child
  }) : _appThemeKey = appThemeKey, super(child: child);

  set appTheme(AppThemeOption theme) {
    switch (theme) {
      case AppThemeOption.experimental:
        (_appThemeKey.currentState as AppThemeState)?.theme = EXPERIMENT_THEME;
        break;
      case AppThemeOption.dev:
        (_appThemeKey.currentState as AppThemeState)?.theme = DEV_THEME;
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(ThemeChanger oldWidget) {
    return oldWidget.theme == theme;
  }

}
```