# How to structure app state so all dependent widgets update when state changes?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have several accounts persisted in SharedPreferences and want to make the current account (which the user choses in a dialog) accessible across the entire app. When the user changes the current account, the UI should automatically update to show that account. However, the app state systems I have tried do not update my StatefulWidgets when the current user changes.

I have tried SharedPreferences, InheritedWidget, Provider, and ChangeNotifier. I haven't been able to listen to SharedPreferences changes, and the other solutions don't update the UI when the state changes.

```dart
// Main.dart

void main() => runApp(
  ChangeNotifierProvider<AppStateManager>.value(
    value: AppStateManager(),
    child: MyApp()
  )
);
```

```dart
class AppStateManager extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _currentStudentIndex;
  int get currentStudentIndex => _currentStudentIndex;

  set currentStudentIndex(int index) {
    _currentStudentIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

```dart
// Code that runs when the user selects a new account

onPressed: () {
  Provider.of<AppStateManager>(context).currentStudentIndex = index;
  Navigator.pop(context);
},
```

```dart
// The state for my StatefulWidget 

_TodayState() {
    getCurrentStudent().then((student) => setState(() {
      _currentStudent = student;
    }));
}

Future<Student> getCurrentStudent() async {
  List<String> students = await PreferencesManager.getStudents();

  final AppStateManager stateManager = Provider.of<AppStateManager>(context);

  Map<String, dynamic> currentStudent = jsonDecode(students[stateManager.currentStudentIndex ?? 0]);

  return Student.fromJson(currentStudent);
}
```

Comment: There are a variety of ways to force a full redraw of your entire app if needed:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778488/force-flutter-to-redraw-all-widgets.

Comment: Would a top-level provider of the student not cause a full rebuild of the entire subtree when the student changes?  https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The user selects a new student in a dialog, updating the current student index in the provider. I would think that the widget tree should rebuild, but my breakpoint in the _TodayState initializer doesn't activate.

Comment: Could it be that the provider value is being updated in a dialog instead of a regular widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried recreating your code from the provided snippets and could reproduce your problem ([here](https://gist.github.com/filiph/0d1c4c7689a52cdf6d926b24aa241893)). You are correctly setting the state and calling `notifyListeners()` but you're not using the state in your build method. You are assuming that `_TodayState` is constructed every time you see it but that's not true. For example, Flutter keeps it in memory if it's in a stack of activities (e.g. when you push a navigator route on top of it).

In other words, your constructor code (`getCurrentStudent().then(...)`) isn't executing as often as you think it is.

To ensure that your UI gets updated, put things in the `build()` method. For example:

```dart
Consumer<AppStateManager>(
  builder: (context, manager, child) => FutureBuilder<Student>(
    future: getCurrentStudent(manager.currentStudentIndex),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
      return Text('Student: ${snapshot.data.name}');
    },
  ),
),
```

This works. [Here](https://gist.github.com/filiph/0d1c4c7689a52cdf6d926b24aa241893#file-so_provider_and_future_fixed-dart)'s the gist. It does fetch students every time the state changes, which might or might not be what you want.

If you absolutely need to mix `setState`, futures and InheritedWidgets, you might need to listen to the provided value manually (with something like `stateManager.addListener(listener)`). But it's better to avoid this, as it can be a source of bugs.

As a general advice with Provider: listen to it (either with `Consumer<...>` or with `Provider.of<...>`) in the build method, not anywhere else.