# How to invoke a rebuild of a stateless widget?

Tags: flutter

### Context

I have two stateless widgets (pages): `HomePage` and `DetailsPage`. Obviously the application starts and launches the `HomePage`. There is a button the user can press to navigate to the `DetailsPage` with a `Navigator.pop()` button to navigate back to the `HomePage`.

I know when the `DetailsPage` is done being used  with the `.whenComplete()` method. It is at this point I want to rebuild the `HomePage` widget.

### Code

This is the minimum reproduction of my behavior.

`main.dart`

```dart
import 'package:example/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: HomePage());
  }
}
```

`home.dart`

```dart
import 'package:example/details.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const name = 'Home Page';
  const HomePage() : super();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: MaterialButton(
          color: Colors.blue,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          child: Text(name),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: DetailsPage.builder),
            ).whenComplete(() => print('Rebuild now.'));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`details.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const name = 'Details Page';
  static WidgetBuilder builder = (BuildContext _) => DetailsPage();
  const DetailsPage();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(name),
            MaterialButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              child: Text('Go Back'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Question

How can I invoke a rebuild of this stateless widget (`HomePage`) at the `.whenComplete()` method callback?

Comment: What's the point of rebuilding this stateless widget ?

Comment: Have you looked into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49804891/force-flutter-navigator-to-reload-state-when-popping

Comment: This example is only for a minimum example. In my actually app I am making a get request to a web server in the build function (`FutureBuilder`) and I know that the web service data update _after_ I leave the second page, so I want that data to be reflected in the first page.

Comment: I don't think that example will work, Nuts. It requires a `StatefulWidget` and my actual implementation doesn't have a state to update. Unless I am able to arbitrarily call `setState` without actually updating a state value (can I?).

Comment: After toying around with the concept, I learned that you can invoke and "empty" `setState` like: `setState(() {});` and it will rebuild your stateless widget. But, Unfortunately, It doesn't really answer my question for a `StatelessWidget`. (Although, I will probably use this as a my actually solution in my app.)

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is being down voted? It meets all requirements of a quality Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Any solution to this with `StatelessWidget`? I have the same use case. The state being changed is on the server and I want the first page to be refreshed with updated data.

Comment: @RoslanAmir I have not found a true (or "safe") way to invoke a rebuild of a stateless widget, unfortunately. Some alternatives I have found include dispatching a dependency change in whatever state management solution you have. For example if you use the "bloc" pattern, you can emit an identical state and rebuild like that.

Comment: However, I don't think the above comment I made is a solution to the original question I have asked.

Comment: Have you looked at the function `markNeedsBuild()`? I couldn't find anything about how to invoke it. Supposedly you can mark a StatelessWidget with this to force a rebuild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force rebuild the widget tree as follows:

```
class RebuildController   {
  final GlobalKey rebuildKey = GlobalKey();
  
  void rebuild() {
    void rebuild(Element el) {
      el.markNeedsBuild();
      el.visitChildren(rebuild);
    }
    (rebuildKey.currentContext as Element).visitChildren(rebuild);
  }

}

class RebuildWrapper extends StatelessWidget  {
  
  final RebuildController controller;
  final Widget child;

  const RebuildWrapper({Key? key, required this.controller, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container(
    key: controller.rebuildKey,
    child: child,
  );

}
```

In your case,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final RebuildController controller = RebuildController();

  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: RebuildWrapper(
        controller: controller,
        child: HomePage(
          rebuildController: controller,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  static const name = 'Home Page';
  final RebuildController rebuildController;

  const HomePage({Key? key, required this.rebuildController}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Hello there!');
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: MaterialButton(
          color: Colors.blue,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          child: const Text(name),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: DetailsPage.builder),
            ).whenComplete(rebuildController.rebuild);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
}

class DetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const name = 'Details Page';
  static WidgetBuilder builder = (BuildContext _) => const DetailsPage();

  const DetailsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text(name),
            MaterialButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              child: const Text('Go Back'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RebuildController   {
  final GlobalKey rebuildKey = GlobalKey();
  
  void rebuild() {
    void rebuild(Element el) {
      el.markNeedsBuild();
      el.visitChildren(rebuild);
    }
    (rebuildKey.currentContext as Element).visitChildren(rebuild);
  }

}

class RebuildWrapper extends StatelessWidget  {
  
  final RebuildController controller;
  final Widget child;

  const RebuildWrapper({Key? key, required this.controller, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container(
    key: controller.rebuildKey,
    child: child,
  );

}
```

But it is unnatural to force rebuild stateless widgets as they are not supposed to be rebuilt. You should use [stateful widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) or other [state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) solutions so that your HomePage will only be updated on **meaningful** state change.

Source - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58513635/17673002)

Comment: This makes sense. I agree with you. There really is not a solution to this question without using genuine state management. Thanks for hack though! This is really interesting

Comment: My pleasure! I was thinking about RepaintBoundary but it doesn't rebuild the widget which is the behavior you wanted.