# When do we need to rebuild the StatelessWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

In the Flutter job interviews, sometimes I am asked how we can rebuild the `StatelessWidget` and the answer to this is to call the `markNeedsBuild()` method of the widget's `Element` or `BuildContext`.

So the question is, are there any cases when we need to rebuild a `StatelessWidget` and it's better to use a `StatelessWidget` instead of the `StatefulWidget`?

I found cases where people wanted to rebuild the `StatelessWidget`, such as [How to invoke a rebuild of a stateless widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65847494/how-to-invoke-a-rebuild-of-a-stateless-widget), but in all these cases it was better to use `StatefulWidget` or state management instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole purpose of the `StatelessWidget` is not to rebuild.
If you require rebuild you have to use `StatefullWidget`.

*I guess the interviewers are trying to trick you xD*

#### Summary

##### Stateless Widget:

- Stateless Widgets are static widgets.
- They do not depend on any data change or any behavior change.
- Stateless Widgets do not have a state, they will be rendered once and will not update themselves, but will only be updated when external data changes.
- For Example: Text, Icon, RaisedButton are Stateless Widgets.

##### Stateful Widget:

- Stateful Widgets are dynamic widgets.
- They can be updated during runtime based on user action or data change.
- Stateful Widgets have an internal state and can re-render if the input data changes or if Widget’s state changes.
- For Example: Checkbox, Radio Button, Slider are Stateful Widgets